# QWebView - QWidget: must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice error

Tags: qt, qwidget, qwebview

Whenever I try to create a new QWebView, the post-build error is

`QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice`

why is this happening?

Yes, i did add `QT += webkit` to the pro file, and it says here

In qwtconfig.pri

CONFIG += QwtDll this line must be ->

#CONFIG += QwtDll

where is qtwconfig.pri?

FWI i'm on a static build

Here is main()

```
#include "MyWidget.h"
#include <QPlastiqueStyle>
#include <QtPlugin>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebView>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qico)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

QApplication app(argc, argv);

app.setStyle(new QPlastiqueStyle);
app.setFont(QFont("Calibri"));
MyWidget widget;
widget.show();

QWebView w;
    w.show();

return app.exec();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation mentions Webkit may not work as a static library.

From the [Platform and Compiler Notes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/platform-notes.html) page:

> WebKit is only supported as a dynamically built library. Static linkage is not supported.

Try dynamic linking instead.

Comment: How do I force webkit to be dynamically linked?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a `QApplication` object in order to use any widget based class and it must be created first, so your `main()` should look something like this..

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWebView w;
    w.show();    
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Then your executable is somehow creating a QWidget based object before a QApplication object. Perhaps try a clean build and make sure you are running the executable you think you are running. If you have a minimal selection of source code that can reproduce the problem then post it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating a `QApplication`, make sure you're not statically allocating the object.

**Don't do this**

```
QWebView w;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another source of this error can be linking to the wrong version of a Qt library -  a release version for a debug build or vice versa.